# URL on apache server does not default to the .php file after / has been added

Tags: php, apache, url, path, dns

Generally a url that looks like this:
http://www.domain.com/product.php/12/

will open up product.php and serve the /12/ as request parameters, which then my PHP script can process to pull out the right product info. However when I migrated this whole site, after developing it, to a new server, I get a 404 error, because on that server it's not defaulting to the mother directory/file in case of an absence of requested directories.

I vaguely remember learning that this is generally a common apache function but I can't seem to recall how to set it up or how to manipulate it.. if there's an .htaccess method to achieve this that would be great.

Comment: Just wondering.. why are you using the slash to pass param's?

Comment: Because using question marks is out of fashion and not SEO friendly.

Answer (score 2):

What you're referring to is mod_rewrite. The official docs for it are here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

You would configure it either in your VHost definition (recommended) or in an .htaccess file.

Assuming that you want to map all requests to a resource that Apache cannot serve (such as files that don't exist) to products.php you can use the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /products.php?request=$1 [NC,L]
```

You can then use `$_GET['request']` to get the path requested and take it from there, depending on what you want to do. I'd normally recommend letting mod_rewrite handle parsing the request and passing the proper attributes to your PHP, but if you're not familiar with mod_rewrite it's probably easier to do it in your PHP.

Answer (score 1):

you can use mod rewrite engine to map this to

```
http://www.domain.com/product.php?arg=12
```

Mod rewrite details: http://forum.modrewrite.com

Sample:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^files/([^/]+)/(.+) files.php?app=$1&file=$2 [NC]
```

this rewrite rule will map any request containing *files/firstrPart/secondpart* to the script *files.php*

everything between the first and second slash after files will be passed as parameter *app* and the rest as *file*

Basicly you define a regex with some subpaterns and state which script should really be called.

You cna refer to the subpatterns with $n where n is the 1 based index of the pattern.

Have fun.

NOTE this is a extreme simplification of mod rewrite. Please do some research before you use it because this might go terribly wrong...

Comment: I know of this method but there's an easier way to do this without mapping it to GET variables. I use the simpler method on every other server, because Apache has a characteristic where it defaults to the mother directory if the content is not found, so the path i show above ultimately runs category.php without any mod-rewrite stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The directive you're looking for is "AcceptPathInfo on".  mod_negotiations MultiViews feature would also give you the option of not including the ".php" which is another common one people abuse mod_rewrite to do.

Comment: This seems to be more along the track. I don't care if I omit the .php or not.. this is how I've been building for months now and I'd like to just keep it that way.

Comment: So that AcceptPathInfo is a directive I would add to the .htaccess file? Or do i need to tinker with httpd.conf?

Comment: The manual talks about the acceptable context for each directive: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo

It's accepted in htaccess when AllowOverride includes FileInfo.